# cannot convert int to int *

Tags: c++, c

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "conio.h"

void swap(int *x,int *y);

void main()
{
int a=10,b=20;
swap(a,b);
printf("value of a=%d and b=%d");
getch();
}

void swap(int *x,int *y)

{
  if(x!=y)
     {
      *x ^= *y;
         *y ^= *x;
         *x ^= *y;

     }
}
```

// I'm getting .. cann't convert int to int * ...

can anybody tell me why so . and how to solve it
regards.

hoping for quick and positive response.

Comment: Your call to `printf()` is also missing arguments. It should be `printf("value of a=%d and b=%d", a, b);`.

Comment: Apart from your problem at hand, some remarks: conio is not a standard header, stdio should not be included via double quotes and void main is not in the standard, either. While it may work in your given toolchain, writing portable and standard conformant code is probably a good idea.

Comment: Which language are you aiming for? Don't just tag language tags on. And [get a book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list), sounds like you need to learn fundamentals.

Comment: Unrelated to the question, you should not be using that swap algorithm unless you know full well what it does and why. You should read up about it: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xor_swap

Comment: 15.6k score and such simple mistake?

Comment: And the XOR hack fails catastrophically if a and b are aliases. Just use a temporary.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Your call to `swap()` should include ampersands:

```
swap(&a,&b);
```

`swap` is expecting pointers to `int`, so you need to take `a` and `b`'s addresses when passing them in.

Comment: Yes, just what i was gonna say, so +1

Comment: or equivalently `void swap(int *x,int *y)` should be `void swap(int & x,int & y)` (along with modified body of course)

Comment: @doc: This is not true for C, which is also one of the tags (just to be complete and pedantic)

Comment: I think the _correct_ solution to the whole delimma is for people to actually *decide what language they are using*. Contrary to popular belief, C code is _not_ the same as C++ code.